# deserialize http response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i'm consuming (not mine) an api that build with soap structure.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
     <somePrefix:someNodeName xmlns="ulrWithNoPrefix" xmlns:somePrefix="urlWithPrefix"
    xmlns:anotherPrefix="UrlForAnotherprefix xmlns:AttributePrefix="UrlForAttributePrefix>
     <anotherPrefix:childNode1>value</anotherPrefix:childNode1>
     <anotherPrefix:childNode2>value</anotherPrefix:childNode2>
     <anotherPrefix:childNode3>value</anotherPrefix:childNode3>
     <anotherPrefix:childNode3 AttributePrefix:AttributeName="attributeValue/>
  </somePrefix:someNodeName>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to build a C# object out of it.
sure i can go on each node , extract the inner text and populate custom type but i understood this could be done for (i would sill need to build the type).
i have tried to use the built in deserialize mechanism  in the httpClient  , and also downloaded protobuf-net and tried my luck there but also failed.

i have the foloowing method to deal with the connection :

public void RunPostTask(string url, string req)
        {
            string res = "";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Content = new StringContent(req);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");

`var task =
            client.PostAsync(url, request.Content).ContinueWith((TaskResponse) =>
        {
            TaskResponse.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var response = TaskResponse.Result;
            var ReadTask = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            ReadTask.Wait(10000);
            res = ReadTask.Result;

        }).ContinueWith((err) =>
            {
                if (err.Exception != null)
                {
                    res = err.Exception.ToString();
                }
            });
        task.Wait(10000);
    }`

i would like to deserialize the res string (which a typical structure is shown above)

Also would like to know if the way i use the HttpClient is correct , or a better design is preferable ?

Thanks 
Gilad

Comment: Can you not just add a reference to the service (you'll need the WSDL document for the service), .NET will generate proxy classes for you.

Comment: i have the wsdl and the xsd's but all location and target namespaces are wrong.They gave me some static files because the "live" files of the service are not formatted well.When i'm trying to add referenace to the service or create proxy file by myself with wsdl.exe i'm failing due to bad formatted xsd files.I can't tell them - fix it,i need to find a solution.....i have created a static wsdl and xsd's and with SoapUI manage to create all the soap request/response.

Comment: i have tweak the wsdl file to use the ip address of the service instead of the dns name and that was all needed to be able reference the wsdl file and creating the code behind.
i'm not sure if it is going to help any on but what i did was :

1. if any xsd are included, change in  **types** --> **xsd:schema** -->**xsd:include** the **schemaLocation** attribute to your static file location.

2. change the **location** element in the **wsdlsoap:address** element in the **service** element to use ip address and not the dns name.

Comment: 3.for each xsd imported file within other xsd file i have change the **schemaLocation** attribute of the **xsd:import** element in the **xsd:schema** element to the static file location.


after i made these 3 changes i was able to use wsdl.exe tool or Add Reference for WCF successfully. 
Thanks for the 2 obvious notes from CodeCaster and Chris Diver to point me back to track.
some time you need a simple "Why not.." to make you rethink again......

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.